# Binomial coefficients that sum to a perfect square

Tags: binomial-coefficients, square-numbers

I was wondering about a property of a sum I recently saw. $${8\choose2}+{9\choose 2}+{15\choose2} + {16\choose2}=17^2$$
And if we increment the terms
$${9\choose3}+{10\choose 3}+{16\choose3} + {17\choose3}=38^2$$
Is it coincidence? I expanded them out into factorials but that did not reveal anything to me.

Comment: Does the pattern of $\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n+1}{k}+\binom{n+7}{k}+\binom{n+8}{k}$ work for any other values?

Comment: @SirJective Regrettably I don't know how to use programs to check, so I'm not sure

Comment: Something that might be interesting to consider would be the sum of the first $n$ odd numbers is $n^2$, maybe  the values of these could be split up into those sums?

Comment: For $k=2$, the sum boils down to $n^2 + (n+7)^2$, so we're looking at pythagorean triples. e.g. it'll work for $n=5$.

Comment: $$\binom{21}{2}+\binom{22}{2}+\binom{28}{2}+\binom{29}{2}=35^2,$$ $$\binom{22}{3}+\binom{23}{3}+\binom{29}{3}+\binom{30}{3}=105^2,$$

Comment: Aw jeez!  for ${m \choose 2} + {{m+1} \choose 2} = \frac {m(m-1)}{2!} + \frac{m(m+1)}{2!} = \frac {m^2 - m + m^2 + m}{2} = m^2$.  So those are just pythagorean triplets.  $8^2 + 15^2 = 17^2$  Don't know how the threes work out.  (I've *never* notices this.)

Comment: The original solution and @Oleg567 solution are the only two up to $10^6$.

Answer (score 2):

I began to explore this numerically in Mathematica. For $n\ge6$, let $$f(n) = \sqrt{\binom{n}{n-6}+\binom{n+1}{n-6}+\binom{n+7}{n-6}+\binom{n+8}{n-6}}$$

What I did was evaluated this expression  for $n \in [6,10000]$. Any integral result was given a $1$ and all non-integers received a $0$. The total was summed to count the number of integral results...

```
f[n_, k_] := Sqrt[Binomial[n, k] + Binomial[n + 1, k] + Binomial[n + 7, k] + Binomial[n + 8, k]]

Total[Table[If[f[n, n - 6] \[Element] Integers, 1, 0], {n, 6, 10000}]]
```

The result was $3$. Which just gives the base case, as well as the two provided by the OP. Hope this helps as a starting point.